# How to "de-align my TD's"

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a new page with PHP and linking to a database for an online store.

I have 2 `<td>` elements that keeps on center lining up horizontally. One has an include (right) and the other has a categories table, linked to the database query.

```
    <table align="center" border="0" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td id="menu" width="20%" valign="top">
                <?php include("../shop/includes/compushop_includes.php")?>
            </td>
            <td id="content" width="80%" border="0">
                <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Content" -->
                <p align="center">[content]</p>
                <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want the left `<td>` (with the include) to stay at the top while the right `<td>` extends as the database extends.

I have tried `[vertical-align:top]` and `[valign="top"]`, but I keep getting the same result.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what contains the included file?

Comment: Using this fiddle, can you explain your issue?  This extends fine, but obviously there's something different in your situation.  What is it? http://jsfiddle.net/hfwqsxqy/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
valign="top"
```

should do the work. There is possibility some CSS stylesheet overrides it.

Comment: Thank you verry mutch. I totally overlooked it. There was indeed a override in my styles.

Comment: Yeah, he did, but forgot to remove inline styles which override it.